# Find out if user exists in a sum when joining multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got 3 tables:
`submissions`, `submissions_votes`, and `users`. My current query:

```
SELECT s.*, u.username, u.avatar, SUM(sv.up) helpfulVotes 
FROM submissions s 
INNER JOIN users u 
  ON s.user_id = u.id 
LEFT JOIN submissions_votes sv 
  ON s.id = sv.submission_id 
WHERE s.id = 23 
GROUP BY s.id
```

Will return for me the submission details, the user who submitted it, and the amount of helpfulVotes on the submission (which comes from the `submissions_votes` table).

This works fine, but what I'd like to do is test for a condition within the SUM(sv.up) to see if the any of the users within that sum matches a particular user_id from `submissions`.

I was thinking of doing something like this but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT s.*, u.username, u.avatar, SUM(sv.up) helpfulVotes,
SUM (IF(sv.user_id = 15, count, 1)) as currentUserVoted, <---- ???
FROM submissions s 
INNER JOIN users u 
  ON s.user_id = u.id 
LEFT JOIN submissions_votes sv 
  ON s.id = sv.submission_id
WHERE s.id = 23 
GROUP BY s.id
```

How can I see if there is a match within that sum to the current user's id (in this case, 15)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use condition in `SUM()` just like `SUM (sv.user_id = 15)` will give you the count for user 15

```
SELECT 
  s.*,
  u.username,
  u.avatar,
  SUM(sv.up) helpfulVotes,
  SUM(sv.user_id = 15) AS currentUserVoted 
FROM
  submissions s 
  INNER JOIN users u 
    ON s.user_id = u.id 
  LEFT JOIN submissions_votes sv 
    ON s.id = sv.submission_id 
WHERE s.id = 23 
GROUP BY s.id
```

or if you want  to sum another column based on user id you can use `CASE`

```
SUM (CASE WHEN sv.user_id = 15 THEN sum_other_col ELSE 0 END) as currentUserVoted
```